# XCode can't find wrong .app file

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I changed the name of my app from X to Y. It was working before, but for some reason it no longer is working after doing a fresh pull. It's giving me this error (from YTests):

```
ld: file not found: <DerivedData Directory>/X.app/X
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It's looking for X.app instead of Y.app. I've looked through the build settings and it is Y.app everywhere. It's looking for the wrong file inside of Tests. When I disable testing, I can run the app but I still get the error. Any suggestions?

Note: I'm using Xcode6-Beta5.

Comment: Run `Product > Clean`

Comment: Already tried that and it didn't work. I've also tried deleting the derived data, and still didn't work. Thanks! @toasted_flakes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After digging around, I realized that this was the actual cause of the error. What confused me is that it was working for a while, and then it stopped all of a sudden.

[xcode 4 fails to initiate unit tests (with linker error) after I created a new scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302362/xcode-4-fails-to-initiate-unit-tests-with-linker-error-after-i-created-a-new-s)

The solution is:

1. Go to build settings of the test target.
2. Search for your old app name.
3. Replace old app name with new app name. (Linking -> Bundle Loader -> Debug & Release)