# iOS: Linker errors with OCUnit integration

Tags: ios

I am adding OCUnit test case target to my existing iOS project. I have followed the tutorials from below links and done it. It created a new target for "MyAppTests" and .m, .h files. I added SenTestingKit.framework also.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/02-Setting_Up_Unit_Tests_in_a_Project/setting_up.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002143-CH3-SW1

http://twobitlabs.com/2011/06/adding-ocunit-to-an-existing-ios-project-with-xcode-4/

But when i click on "Product" menu "Test" option, it gives always the following linker errors.

[image]

I tried solving errors by following these links and the solution they have provided,
[xcode 4 fails to initiate unit tests (with linker error) after I created a new scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302362/xcode-4-fails-to-initiate-unit-tests-with-linker-error-after-i-created-a-new-s)
[OCUnit testing an embedded framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867251/ocunit-testing-an-embedded-framework)

but, none of the solution worked for me, its still giving linker errors as it is. Please help on resolving these errors.

Thank you.

Comment: I resolved it myself, i just removed everything related to test target and created new test target and followed the same as per below Apple link, and it worked as expected! http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/02-Setting_Up_Unit_Tests_in_a_Project/setting_up.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002143-CH3-SW1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it myself, i just removed everything related to test target and created new test target and followed the same as per below Apple link, and it worked as expected!

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/02-Setting_Up_Unit_Tests_in_a_Project/setting_up.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002143-CH3-SW1