# SenTestCase linker error iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4.5

I'm trying to write test cases for my iOS app. However, there seems to be some problem regarding SenTesting framework. I'm getting the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SenTestCase", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_testSmartDiary in testSmartDiary.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_testAddTask in testAddTask.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_testAddContacts in testAddContacts.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SenTestCase", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_testSmartDiary in testSmartDiary.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_testAddTask in testAddTask.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_testAddContacts in testAddContacts.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I don't know what is going wrong. I have added the SenTestingFramework. It is probably happening because I'm using two different machines to develop the same project. Do I need to specify some path? I read the solution given here: [iOS: Linker errors with OCUnit integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664552/ios-linker-errors-with-ocunit-integration)
 but it is not feasible to delete the target and add the things again every time I switch machines. Is there a permanent solution to this? Please help

Comment: yes, its because its missing senTesting Framework in your project.

Comment: I've already added the framework

Comment: then there would be something missing. for that one need to take a look on code and project

Comment: yes there must be some problem with settings.. how can I share the whole project?

Comment: I followed this link: http://twobitlabs.com/2011/06/adding-ocunit-to-an-existing-ios-project-with-xcode-4/#comment-1804 the problem was solved after I followed the steps.

Comment: good, congratulations